# Get empty array when class containing spaces

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

Python 2.7

I want to get each of the new's background image url and titles, but I use xpath always get empty array when I try to get image url.

Here is what I try:

```
scrapy shell http://www.wownews.tw/fashion/movie
```

and then

```
response.body
```

I can see the html data on terminal. But when I type

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="text ng-scope"]')
```

get empty array, I thought it should be work.

Is the problem happen because class containing spaces ?

How to fix it ?  Any help would be appreciated.

I try the command still get empty array

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), "text ng-scope")]')
```

Comment: I see `ng` and it can means that this page use JavaScript to load data. Open browser, turn off JavaScript and load your page in browser to see what `Scrapy` can see.

Comment: I don't see tags with class `"text ng-scope"` in HTML. Maybe you see it in JavaScript in `response.body`. There are tags with class `"text" (`response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "text")]') `) but not with class `"ng-scope" (`response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "ng-scope")]')`). As for me `ng-scope` may not be `class` but `attribute`.

Comment: I try close javascript and open it. The website will stuck.

Comment: I can find attribute `ng-repeat` (`response.xpath('//div[@ng-repeat]')`) or `ng-bind` (`response.xpath('//div[@ng-bind]')`) but not `ng-scope` (`response.xpath('//div[@ng-scope]')`)

Comment: Website stuck because it can't work without JavaScript. As I know `Scrapy` doesn't use `Selenium` (you would have to create project and add some code with `Selenium`) so it can't get data created with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, as far as I know some situation use `Selenium` because simulate click listener on website, but my url just open it and scrapy data. If I use `Selenium` will work for what ?  Do I miss something ?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I find I can get the data from their ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is everything what you need

```
import json
import scrapy


class ListingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'listing'

    start_urls = ['http://api.wownews.tw/f/pages/site/558fd617913b0c11001d003d?category=5590a6a3f0a8bf110060914d&children=true&limit=48&page=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = json.loads(response.body)['results']

        for item in items:
            yield item
```

Refer to https://medium.com/@yashpokar/scrape-any-website-in-the-internet-without-using-splash-or-selenium-68a6c9733369